# Bukkit Generating Worlds

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to generate a world I have it to currently generate to empty. That's what I want but now I want to generate a square or land for each player when they join. I would like to make it look like a grid. The squares will not connect. I can do it in a diagonal fashion but I don't know how to go about making it a grid.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
    for(int z = 0; z < 32; z++) {
        Location l = new Location(getClashWorld(), x, 64,  z);
        getClashWorld().getBlockAt(l).setType(Material.GRASS);
    }
}
```

That's how I create a 32x32 plot of land in the world and i can just change the x and z along with the x < and the z < to move it diagonally. How would I make this into a grid?

Comment: Your approach may be very inefficient. You should use [world generators](https://bukkit.org/threads/how-to-create-custom-world-generators.79066/) instead.

Comment: I have a world generator in my plugin I just don't want a ton of unused plots

Answer (score 1):

You could make 32x32 plot of land by using:

```
int y = 64;
for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++){
  for(int z = 0; z < 32; z++){
    Location location = new Location(world, x, y, z);
    location.getBlock().setType(Material.GRASS);
  }
}
```

So, you could make a 4x4 grid by using:

```
int y = 64; //the position on the y axis that this plot will be created

for(int xTimes = 0; xTimes < 4; xTimes++){//xTimes < 4 makes it so this will create 4 plots on the x axis
  for(int zTimes = 0; zTimes < 4; zTimes++){//zTimes < 4 makes it so this will create 4 plots on the z axis

    //create the plot of land
    for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++){//x < 32 makes it so this will create a plot 32 long
      for(int z = 0; z < 32; z++){//z < 32 makes it so this will create a plot 32 wide

        //get the x and z locations for the plot
        //multiplying the below values by 64 makes it so there will be a 32x32 gap between each plot
        //(below multiplication value - plot size = gap), so the gap will be 64 - 32 = 32 blocks
        int xPos = x + (xTimes * 64);
        int zPos = z + (zTimes * 64);

        //get the location for the block, and then set the block to grass (or set it to whatever you want)
        Location location = new Location(world, xPos, y, zPos);
        location.getBlock().setType(Material.GRASS);

      }
    }

  }
}
```

If you wanted to make the plot a few blocks deeper, you could just add another `for` loop below

```
for(int z = 0; z < 32; z++)
```

And make it iterate through the `y` values that you would like the plot to be at. For example, if you wanted the plots to be 4 blocks high, going from `y = 60` to `y = 64`, you could use:

```
for(int y = 60; y <= 64; y++)
```

If you wanted to create the plots when you need to, you could use:

```
public void generatePlot(int xTime, int zTime){
  for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++){
    for(int z = 0; z < 32; z++){

      int xPos = x + (xTime * 64);
      int zPos = z + (zTime * 64);

      Location location = new Location(world, xPos, y, zPos);
      location.getBlock().setType(Material.GRASS);

    }
  }
}
```

You could then keep a record of the amount of times a plot has been created, and generate new plots accordingly. For example, if you wanted there to be 10 plots on the x axis, you could use:

```
int plotsCreated = 100; //load this from a configuration file, or something
int xTime = plotsCreated % 10;
int yTime = Math.floor(plotsCreated / 10);

generatePlot(xTime, yTime);

plotsCreated++;
//save the new plotsCreated variable somewhere
```

Comment: Will this allow me to only create the plot when I need one or will it generate them all at once

Comment: @WilliamRandall I just updated my answer to include how you could create new plots when you want them

Comment: Ok so now with the generate plot method is there a way to make it 32 plots wide by infinite long ? Because I can't limit the amount of plots. You get what I'm saying?

Comment: @WilliamRandall Yea, in the last code example, use 32 instead of 10, and it will be 32 wide by infinite long

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final int w = 32;
final int h = 32;
int offset = 0;

      for(int x = 0; x < w; x ++){
            for(int y = 0; y < h; y ++){
                if(((x + offset) & 1) == 0){
                   //generate block A
                }else{
                   //generate block B
                }

                if(offset == 0) 
                   offset = 1;
                else
                   offset = 0;
            }
        }
```

That should generate a grid. It checks